# What kind / type / model relay is this?

Tags: relay, identification

I got a bunch of electronic components from someone, but some of them came without any ID. The one below is a relay, but I think the upper enclosure is missing (containing the model/type).

It looks like a relay and the upper part can move, connecting the two metal parts at the left top and right top.

As you can see, it has 6 pins, 4 on the left side, 2 on the right.

Does anybody can give some more information about this relay?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a small power relay (probably >2A) with a DC coil. You can apply voltage to it from a lab supply and figure out the proper coil voltage. It will probably pull in around 60% of rated voltage. Wild guess, 24VDC or possibly 12VDC coil.

I would not suggest using it for anything serious without a cover-too easy for crud to get into the contacts.

Comment: Thanks ... well I'm more intending to use microcontrollers so I probably don't need this, but I just wondered what it is. I'm using simple (closed) 220V relays which work with 3V/5V to switch them on/off.